# symfony doctrine order by

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to use doctrine and take the values ordered, but I cannot.

I try so:

```
$articlesB = $this
                ->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager()
                ->getRepository('theBundle:Article')
                ->findAll(array('date' => 'ASC'));
```

Do you know howw to take this values ordered by date? A column is named date and take all the dates. I want to have this orderer.

Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use findBy instead of findAll with an empty array for the first argument (selection criteria) and your sorting array as the second argument.

```
$articlesB = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('theBundle:Article')
            ->findBy(array(),array('date' => 'ASC'));
```

In this case I looked at the actual source code.  You would think that findAll() would work but nope.  It never passes the sorting criteria on.

Comment: `findAll` is just a shortcut for `findBy(array())` (http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#149-157) so this would be the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an ArticleRepostory and in it:

```
public function getOrderedArticles()
{
    $return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
            "SELECT a FROM theBundle:Article a "
            . "ORDER BY a.date ASC"
    );
}
```

so that your controller could do

```
$articlesB = $this
                ->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager()
                ->getRepository('theBundle:Article')
                ->getOrderedArticles();
```

Comment: Actually, the built in repository method findBy can handle sorting as well as limit/offset without any additional coding.

Comment: It was exactly what I need, and very fast! Thanks!